# what's the function of LODWORD and HIDWORD?

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation, c

I'm trying to figure out what  does this piece of code exactly:

```
  LODWORD(fMax) = *(_DWORD *)v12;
  HIDWORD(fMax) = v13;
```

I was reading on `IDA\Plugins\defs.h` the definition, but I don't understand what does exactly to redo the same thing on Java.

I'll be really really glad if someone of you can help me.

Comment: `LODWORD()` takes the low DWORD from `fMax`, and `HIDWORD()` the high DWORD. Basically, if you got an `__int64` like this: `x = 0xFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAA`, `LODWORD(x)` is `0xAAAAAAAA` and `HIDWORD(x)` is `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: So this two variables are basically changin the value of fMax. for example as you said, if i had fMax = 0xFFFFFFFFAAAAAAAA and v12 = 0xFFCD0000... the final value of LODWORD(fMax) would be 0xFFFFFFFFFFCD0000. i'm right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, i assume you omitted a `&`, and the first expression should read `...*(_DWORD *) &v12`, as you want to select the low 32 bits from v12, instead of treating v12 as a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

This pattern is typical for assigning a 64-bit value to a variable on a 32 bit system - you calculate each 32-bit value separately, then push them into the high and low 32 bits of the 64 bit value.

In Java, your first assignment would be

```
fMax=(fMax & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) | (v12 & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF)
```

and the second would be

```
fMax=(fMax & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) | (((long)v13<<32) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000)
```

Of course, `fMax` is a 64 bit long here.

You can omit the `& 0xFFFFFFFF00000000` from the second expression, as you know those bits will be zero after the left shift. And you can omit the `& 0x00000000FFFFFFFF` from the first expression if `v12` is an `int`, since the high bits will be zero anyway in a 32 bit integer. But the java compiler will probably optimize these away anyway, and i wanted to write the statements in a way that makes clear which bits are taken from `fMax`, and which from `v12` and `v13`.

Comment: Thank you, i've understood but now i found this `SHIDWORD(v10)` i assume this is something like do `fMax = (fMax & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) | (v10 + 1) ` i'm right?

Comment: SHIDWORD is the sign extended HIDWORD. The SHIDWORD of a negative 32-bit value is FFFFFFFF, and the SHIDWORD of a positive 32-bit value is 0. The `+1` does not apply to the value, as in your `v10 + 1`, it applies to the pointer - one DWORD after the one at the address of `v10`.

Comment: How can I convert that in simple C code? IDA interpreted this `mov [rsp+56], eax` to this `LODWORD(v1) = v2;`, `v1` goes to a unknown/undocumented function.